# How to factor $ax^{2}+bxy+cy^{2},\,a\neq 0$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, quadratics

Question: Factor: $3x^{2}-5xy-12y^{2}$

Answer: $(x-3y)(3x+4y)$

What are the exact steps to finding this answer from the original question (factored form from standard form, respectively)?

Comment: Do you mean $a\neq 0$?

Comment: This is another example which I solved: 5x2-14x+8 = (x-10)(x-4)

Comment: @ArthurAlexKarapetov For your "other" example you have, as required $10\times 4 = 5 \times 8=40$ and $10+4=14$ but your factorisation doesn't work - multiply it out. Instead do $5x^2-14x+8=5x^2-10x-4x+8=5x(x-2)-4(x-2)=(5x-4)(x-2)$ where you use $10+4=14$ to split the middle term.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To factor $3x^2 - 5xy - 12y^2$, we first split the linear term, then factor by grouping.  To split the linear term, we must find two numbers with product $3 \cdot -12 = -36$ and sum $-5$.  They are $-9$ and $4$.  Hence,
\begin{align*}
3x^2 - 5xy - 12y^2 & = 3x^2 - 9xy + 4xy - 12y^2 && \text{split the linear term}\\
& = 3x(x - 3y) + 4y(x - 3y) && \text{factor by grouping}\\
& = (3x + 4y)(x - 3y) && \text{extract the common factor}
\end{align*}
To check that the answer is correct, we multiply the factors.  Observe that doing so amounts to performing the steps of the factorization in reverse order.

In your second example of $5x^2 - 14x + 8$, to split the linear term, we must find two numbers with product $5 \cdot 8 = 40$ and sum $-14$.  They are $-10$ and $-4$.  Hence,
\begin{align*}
5x^2 - 14x + 8 & = 5x^2 - 10x - 4x + 8 && \text{split the linear term}\\
               & = 5x(x - 2) - 4(x - 2) && \text{factor by grouping}\\
               & = (5x - 4)(x - 2) && \text{extract the common factor}
\end{align*}

In general, if $ax^2 + bx + c$, $a \neq 0$, is a quadratic polynomial with rational coefficients, then it factors with respect to the rationals if there exist two rational numbers with product $ac$ and sum $b$.  In particular, if $r$, $s$, $t$, and $u$ are rational numbers such that 
$$ax^2 + bx + c = (rx + s)(tx + u) \tag{1}$$
then $a = rt$, $b = ru + st$, and $c = su$.  If you perform the multiplication
\begin{align*}
(rx + s)(tx + u) & = rx(tx + u) + s(tx + u)\\
                 & = rtx^2 + rux + stx + su\\
                 & = rtx^2 + (ru + st)x + su\\
                 & = ax^2 + bx + su
\end{align*} 
you will notice that we can obtain $a = rt$, $b = ru + st$, and $c = su$ by matching coefficients, as Dietrich Burde stated.

We can prove this assertion by treating equation 1 as an algebraic identity.  Since it is an identity, equation 1 holds for each value of the variable.  In particular, it holds for $x = 0$, $x = 1$, and $x = -1$.  Setting $x = 0$ in equation 1 yields 
$$c = su \tag{2}$$
Setting $x = 1$ in equation 1 yields 
\begin{align*}
a + b + c & = (r + s)(t + u)\\
          & = r(t + u) + s(t + u)\\
          & = rt + ru + st + su \tag{3}
\end{align*} 
Since $c = su$, we can cancel $c$ from the left hand side and $su$ from the right hand side of equation 3 to obtain
$$a + b = rt + ru + st \tag{4}$$
Setting $t = -1$ in equation 2 yields
\begin{align*}
a - b + c & = (r - s)(t - u)\\
          & = r(t - u) - s(t - u)\\
          & = rt - ru - st + su \tag{5}
\end{align*}
Since $c = su$, we can cancel $c$ from the LHS and $su$ from the RHS of equation 5 to obtain 
$$a - b = rt - ru - st \tag{6}$$
Adding equations $4$ and $6$ yields
$$2a = 2rt \tag{7}$$
Dividing both sides of equation 7 by $2$ yields 
$$a = rt \tag{8}$$
Since $a = rt$, we can cancel an $a$ from the LHS of equation 4 and $rt$ from the RHS of equation 4 to obtain
$$b = ru + st \tag{9}$$
Our derivation of equations 2, 8, and 9 proves the claim.

Answer (score 2):

I propose a different (I think more direct for early students) way to factor it.

You can treat one of the variables as if it was another number, for example $y$. You can just then:

$$3x^2-5xy-12y^2=0,$$
and using the general solution:
$$x = \frac{5y\pm y\sqrt{25+144}}{6}=y\frac{5\pm 13}{6}$$

The solutions are $3y$ and $-4y/3$, and so the factoring is:
$$3(x-3y)(x+\frac{4}{3}y)=0$$

Answer (score 2):

Here is a an elementary way to find the factorization, of, say $3x^2-5xy-12y^2$.
Just make the Ansatz 
$$
3x^2-5xy-12y^2=(ax+by)(cx+dy)=acx^2 + (ad + bc)xy + bdy^2.
$$ 
Comparing the coefficients we immeadiately see that $ac=3, ad+bc=-5, bd=-12$. A solution is $(a,b,c,d)=(1,-3,3,4)$.

Comment: It looks like you meant $ad \color{red}{+} bc = -5$.

Answer (score 1):

If $y=0$, then $(x,y)=(0,0)$ is the only solution. Otherwise:

$$ax^2+bxy+cy^2=y^2\left(a\left(\frac{x}{y}\right)^2+b\left(\frac{x}{y}\right)+c\right)$$

The paranthesised expression is a quadratic in $\frac{x}{y}$, which you should know how to factor.

Answer (score 1):

Solve the equation for $x$, with the usual formula.

$$x=\frac{-by\pm\sqrt{(by)^2-4a(cy^2)}}{2a}=\frac{-b\pm\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}y.$$

Then factor using these roots

$$ax^2+bxy+cy^2=a\left(x-\frac{-b+\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}y\right)\left(x-\frac{-b-\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}y\right).$$

With the given example,

$$3x^2-5xy+12y^2=3(x-3)(x+\frac43y)=(x-3)(3x+4).$$

Answer (score 1):

You can look at $f(x,y)=ax^2+bxy+cy^2$ as the homogeneous form of $g(x)=ax^2+bx+c$

If $g(x)=(px+q)(rx+s)$ then $f(x,y)=(px+qy)(rx+sy)$

This works because, from the factorisation of $g(x)$ it is clear that $pr=a, ps+qr=b, qs=c$.

It is normally straightforward, as in other answers, to prove that this works, but if all you want is a solution, then just take the $y$s out at the beginning, and put them back at the end so that each term or expression has the same order.

Answer (score 0):

HINT: dividing by $xy\ne 0$ we get
$$3\frac{x}{y}-5-12\frac{y}{x}=0$$ and now set $$t=\frac{x}{y}$$
this is equivalent to $$3t^2-5t-12=0$$

Comment: thank you for downvoting!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: This doesn't help. For problems with one variable, x, I know you have to find two numbers that give the sum of "b" and give the product of "c". This question should follow similar parameters.

Comment: from where do you know that this doesn't help?

Comment: @ArthurAlexKarapetov: would be more friendly to say "sorry I don't understand where you are leading me".

Comment: In other words, you should have started by dividing by $y^2$ to make the equivelence transparent. Dividing by $xy$ is really strange, since you get $3t-5-12t^{-1}=0$, which you then have to do something else to get the quadratic equation. Dividing by $y^2$ just works.